# Dynamic URL in Django/HTML

Tags: html, django-templates

```
{% for record in records%}

string1 = 'views.' + record.field1 + record.field2

<a href ="{%url string1 %}>Test this</a>

{%endfor%}
```

Is this possible in HTML / Django ?
My need is to make the variable 'string1' dynamically and pass it into the url.
Request for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `{% with %}`

```
{% with "views."|add:record.field1|add:record.field2 as string1 %}
    <a href="{% url string1 %}">Test this</a>
{% endwith %}
```

but this isn't considered best practice IMO since your effectively putting logic inside your template.

This should be handled by a method on your `record` model instead, probably called `field_url` or something.
This way you don't violate DRY and you won't risk anyone else messing with your url PLUS you'll get a chance of cleaning your urls properly before exposing them.

```
def field_url(self):
    return "views.{0}{1}".format(self.field1, self.field2)
```

and called in your template

```
{% for record in records %}
    <a href="{% url record.field_url %}">My URL</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: added {%endwith%}. Still error" Reverse for 'string1' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. The view for the string1 exists in urls.py

Comment: In first method 'string1' is not available as a populated variable inside the scope {% url string1 %}.

Comment: I missed adding <a> to the first example, sorry!